# Spring Boot (Gradle) app deployed to Google App Engine returns 404 Not Found

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, gradle, google-cloud-platform

I have a Spring Boot (2.1.7) (Gradle project) that I want to deploy to Google App Engine.

I am able to successfully deploy the app (using the [documentation found here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/using-gradle)) but when visiting the app url it returns a 404 Not Found screen:

```
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Not Found</h1>
</body></html>
```

Here's what my `build.gradle` file looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.1.0'
        classpath 'org.akhikhl.gretty:gretty:+'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.akhikhl.gretty'
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'

group = 'com.company'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'jul-to-slf4j'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty'
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    providedCompile 'com.google.appengine:appengine:+'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

gretty {
    httpPort = 8080
    contextPath = '/'
    servletContainer = 'jetty9'  // What App Engine Flexible uses
}

appengine {
    deploy {
        version = "3"
        projectId = "apprealtest"
        stopPreviousVersion = true  // default - stop the current version
        promote = true              // default - & make this the current version
    }
}
```

Here is what my `{projectRoot}/src/main/appengine/app.yaml` file looks like:

```
runtime: java
env: flex

runtime_config:  # Optional
  jdk: openjdk8

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

This is what my `{projectRoot}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml` file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <runtime>java8</runtime>
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

This is what the `{projectRoot}/src/main/java/com/company/hello/HelloApplication.java` looks like:

```
package com.company.hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class HelloApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HelloApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

This is what the `{projectRoot}/src/main/java/com/company/hello/HelloController.java` looks like:

```
package com.company.hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String get() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() + "";
    }

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String getGreeting() {
        return "Greetings!";
    }
}
```

I'm making the call to https://apprealtest.appspot.com and https://apprealtest.appspot.com/greeting.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add to the question the controller and URL you are trying to call ?

Comment: @NattyRoots I updated the question...

Comment: Did you try to launch it using a Tomcat or another web server before using google app engine ? If you followed the linked tutorial I supposed you did [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/quickstart) as well ?

Comment: In the app.yaml you are setting the environment to "standard" while the documentation you are following is for GAE Flexible. If you see the build.gradle file it has the line `servletContainer = 'jetty9'  // What App Engine Flexible uses`. If you wish to run it in flexible, change your app.yaml to `env: flex`.

Comment: @TasosZG I've started with `flex` and later changed this to `standard` as a test. both did not work and result in the same thing

Comment: @NattyRoots yes, it works with Tomcat locally and also with Jetty. But when running it as `gradle appengineRun` it doesn't work and gives me a 404.

Answer (score 1):

To deploy it in GAE Standard you can download this official [SpringBoot for App Engine Standard sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/springboot-appengine-standard).

The instructions are for maven but to do it with Gradle you can simply add this **build.gradle** file:

```
buildscript {    // Configuration for building
  repositories {
    jcenter()    // Bintray's repository - a fast Maven Central mirror & more
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:1.+'    // Latest 1.x.x release
  }
}

repositories {   // repositories for Jar's you access in your code
  maven {
    url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' // SNAPSHOT repository (if needed)
  }
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'java'                              // standard Java tasks
apply plugin: 'war'                               // standard Web Archive plugin
apply plugin: 'com.google.cloud.tools.appengine'  // App Engine tasks
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:+'  // Latest App Engine Api's
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.1.RELEASE'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.1.RELEASE'
    providedCompile 'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25'
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'jul-to-slf4j'
}

group = 'com.google.appengine.demos'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'springboot-appengine-standard'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            from(components.java)
        }
    }
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

And you can deploy it with `gradle appengineDeploy`.

I tested it myself and it worked. If you want to do it in GAE Flexible the corresponding sample would be [this one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/helloworld-springboot) which also has instructions for Maven so you would have to do the necessary migration to Gradle.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. Even using the exact build.gradle file you provided. Or the example.

Answer (score 0):

As I have not found a complete example of spring boot with the Gradle build tool. 
Added a complete example with updated spring boot version 2.2.3 and AppEngine  Gradle plugin 2.2.0.

```
  buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
   }
  dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-gradle-plugin:2.2.0'
  }
 }

 plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'war'
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.3.RELEASE'
  id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
   jcenter()
 }
 configurations.all {
          exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
        exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'jul-to-slf4j'
  }
 dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  compile "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:+"
  providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.0.1'
  providedCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:+"
  providedCompile "com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:+"
  providedCompile 'org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.25'

  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
  compile group: 'net.bytebuddy', name: 'byte-buddy', version: '1.10.3'
}

 apply plugin: "com.google.cloud.tools.appengine"
 appengine {  // App Engine tasks configuration
   run {      // local (dev_appserver) configuration (standard environments only)
    jvmFlags = ['-Ddatastore.backing_store=../../src/main/webapp/WEB- 
   INF/appengine-generated/local_db.bin', '-Dappengine.fullscan.seconds=5']
    port = 8812              // default
  }
  deploy {   // deploy configuration\
    stopPreviousVersion = false  // default - stop the current version
    promote = false              // default - & make this the current version
    version = 'pr'
    projectId = '' 
   }
}
```

This [repo](https://github.com/pravanjan/springboot-appengine-java8) has a complete example and the test case for its controller. hope it would help.